# Is there a policy for homework-type questions?

Tags: discussion

I am not sure what the best course of action is for questions like the one on [the street sign recognition](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/how-to-extract-traffic-signs-from-a-photograph).

I can't help think the author didn't really search for information prior to answering, and it looks like homework to me. Personally, I am inclined to tell an engineering student to go work on the problem himself, and have some fun.

On other hand, if this site is to become a fantastic knowledge base, I should definitely had my street-sign recognition algorithm and see how the community receives it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a homework question policy, not only on this site, but universally across Stack Exchange sites. The policy is that for questions tagged as [homework](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework), people will try to give the OP hints rather than solving the problem for him/her. Homework questions are definitely welcome (that's why the tag exists), but we try not to give full answers, and rather guide the OP in the right direction.

Comment: Currently, only two questions are tagged as such. The question I mentioned is not. Personally, I don't feel I have been around here long enough to retag questions, but nobody else apparently feels the need either. My short experience with SO is that the homework tag is added quite vigorously.

Comment: The right thing to do if you're not sure is to ask, "Is this homework?". I don't necessarily see how this looks like it's homework, because clearly the OP is using many techniques to try and extract the information, and homework assignments generally don't follow such path.

Comment: @Maurits I found more questions tagged as [tag:homework]. Here's a [link](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework).